# Localhost returns This site can’t be reached

Tags: docker

When I do a `docker-compose up`, I get the following message:

> This site can’t be reached: localhost refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am running this code on a Mac Pro. The localhost used to work, but then stopped working. Not sure what I did wrong.

```
version: '2'
services:
  apache:
    image: rafaelcgstz/magento2
    # build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80" # web
      - "9001:9000" # xdebug
      # - "35729:35729" # live reload
    volumes:
      - cleanMagento-sync:/var/www/html:nocopy
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
      - ~/.npm:/var/www/.npm
      # - ~/.nvm:/var/www/.nvm
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=10.254.254.254 remote_connect_back=0"      
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - cleanMagento-network
networks:
  cleanMagento-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  cleanMagento-sync:
    external: true
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

i did a docker ps and got the results below

**RESULT OF DOCKER PS**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
4599fe5ba69b        rafaelcgstz/magento2         "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp       cleanmagento2_apache_1
66acf3523f67        redis                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32783->6379/tcp                          cleanmagento2_redis_1
6862029ed184        mariadb                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3300->3306/tcp                           cleanmagento2_db_1
ae79672e933e        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                             cleanmagento2_phpmyadmin_1
666973686e0f        mailhog/mailhog              "MailHog"                About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp   cleanmagento2_mailhog_1
f01b84dad099        redis                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32782->6379/tcp                          cleanmagento2_redis-session_1
ee96894956f4        eugenmayer/unison:2.51.2.1   "/entrypoint.sh supe…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   5000/tcp                                         cleanmagento2-sync
```

I expect the local host to render the page.

**EDIT:**

i did some tests and now believe its to do with the apache

i did a

> ping 127.0.0.1

this returned :

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
```

i also checked if anyting else was listing on port:

> sudo lsof -i :80 | egrep "PID|LISTEN"

this returned ;

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   860 root    4u  IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   864 _www    4u  IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

i then tested my localhost;

> telnet localhost 80

this returned;

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
```

FINALLY i did a apache config test;

> apachectl configtest

this returned the following ERROR;

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for jon-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

NOT clear if this is the cause of the problem, if so, how to fix it

Comment: Which command exactly gives you the error message? Is it really a `docker-compose up`, or is it a request you send to `localhost:80`?

Comment: hi @fjc its the request to localhost:80

Comment: Is this the full docker-compose file? there is no `db` service there. please post output of `docker ps`

Comment: @Ntwobike- hi. i posted the results of docker ps below

Comment: @Ntwobike -- its not the full docker-compose file. but i figured we dont need all of it